# Azure Data Factory: Access for identities in a different tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, microsoft-entra-id

I have deployed an azure data factory within my own tenant (let's call it `Tenant A`).

I have another tenant (`Tenant B`) where there's a group of users that I would like to give access to this data factory. This group must be managed at **Tenant B**.

Is there a way I can configure this? What should be my approach?

I would like something like the [SCIM API for databricks workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/scim/aad). Which is perfect for my use-case.

I tried looking up online but couldn't find any guide on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately cross tenant user access cannot be shared to ADFs.
You would have to add the tenant B users as either a guest user in tenant A and then give them access to the ADF.

Else you can create an ADF in tenant B that would trigger the pipeline of ADF in tenant A via service principal authentication (SP within the same tenant as the original ADF)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Nandan. Can you please provide me with links to some resources or guides where I can look into this?

Comment: Hi @RehanRajput,  did you try on your Active Directory level? You can assign AD application in ADF and allow the users from that AD application so that they can access. I hope, you'll find some way from there. I'll try to share you some link for that

Comment: Hi @Arya, can you please share some links so I can start digging into it? Thank you so much for helping me out with this. :)